# How to put HH:mm:ss formatted times in CSV so Excel formats them as regular text?

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I'm writing times into a CSV file time using the format HH:mm:ss.  When excel opens the file  it automatically recognizes this column format as time.  Is it possible to prevent Excel from doing this so the column is formatted as regular text?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was recently a similar question on SuperUser: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/330291/how-to-stop-excel-from-auto-formatting-and-making-it-work-like-a-number-crunching/330292)

The same principle as the accepted answer can be employed here if all you want is a CSV that can be opened with Excel without the ill-effects of autoformatting.  You'll need to write your values to the CSV in this format:

```
="yourdatetimehere"
```

Of course the downside is that the equal signs and quotation marks will be stored in your CSV as text.  This means that this will probably cause problems for you if you plan to use the CSV in any context outside Excel.  But as a hack to get around Excel's autoformatting, this should work.

Comment: @Stewbob: Thanks for the edit!  That was kind of boneheaded on my part.

Answer (score 2):

You have no control over formatting in a CSV file, unless you want to go through the full custom-import setup in Excel each time.

If you want to force Excel to treat something as text, then use a proper Excel file, generated using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com)

Comment: I'm generating csv in C#, tried to put 22.22.22 in brackets getting same time format. So you think it is impossible to mark it as text format?

Comment: Since you're on C#, you could just invoke Excel directly and fill in the cells directly.